# How to kill networking to a docker container?

Tags: docker

What approach can I use to kill networking to a docker container (ie: make it unreachable from the host OS)? A typical approach for a non-container would be to alter iptables, but for Docker I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly this way by default. If you don't `expose` any ports and don't run network services in the OS (usually you just run your application), there's nothing to reach in the container.

You might clarify precisely what you mean with "reachable". Reachable from where for what purpose? If you don't expose any ports, your container is not reachable from any other host. Your container may still be "reachable" from other containers within the docker network on the host, so if your concern is other docker containers within the same docker host, docker provides the `--icc=false` flag to disable **inter-container communication**, which by default is enabled. [More info here in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#between-containers).

Comment: By reachable, I mean via a tcp connection from the host OS. I do expose ports, I just want to make them unreachable for a certain time period, then reachable again.

Comment: You should be able to use iptables to do this. Docker runs in the main OS kernel and shares the network stack including iptables. You can use the docker CLI to query for the container's IP. You could also just stop the container and start it later, which might be the simpler approach.